# How to Network to Kubernetes Behind MAAS

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas

I have a router with MAAS behind it and Kubernetes behind the MAAS controller (it has 2 NICs --- one connected to the Kubernetes and one connected to the router). I am trying to connect to a container in Kubernetes with an IP address of 10.12.0.2 from another computer on the router. However, I can't connect.

The MAAS controller has an IP address of 10.11.0.2 and I can connect to that just fine. However, the 10.12.0.0 network is not exposed to the router. How can I connect to the Kubernetes cluster from a computer connected to the router? Is there an automated way I can do this without having to manually bridge IPs in the MAAS for every new container? Also, can I do this in a way that has a minimal impact to the security that having a MAAS node inbetween the Kubernetes cluster and the router provides?

Comment: Hi @user2476265 - you may wish to ask this question in the Juju Discourse forum for greater visibility: https://discourse.jujucharms.com/

Answer (score 1):

First things first... is that container ip, `10.12.0.2`, a `ClusterIP`? If so that may explain a lot of the problems you are having. I wrote the following with a major assumption ... that it is the internal, unexposed ip you get in a container inside a pod. One thing you may try if you haven't already... Try to access that container ip `10.12.0.2` from the MAAS box. Can't access it? I bet it needs to be exposed...

---

I have not tried the exact setup you have. I think what I wrote below may not fully apply because your setup runs through your MAAS server, which complicates things.

Maybe you have already discovered this, but the ClusterIP addresses supplied by most Kubernetes services are only exposed to other machines inside the cluster. There are many ways to expose a service, including many I would not recommend for your situation.

What I describe below is the simplest and best setup I have at this point, which has the benefit of providing a static IP for that service. You can then use the DNS settings in MAAS (or whatever you prefer for DNS) to make an `A` record that points to that IP for that service.

To make this less abstract and bogged down by jargon here's a concrete example... you might:

- deploy Rook/Ceph (`rook.io`) on your k8s cluster
- change the svc for it to have `ServiceType: LoadBalancer`, obtain an IP of `192.168.1.240` for that svc discovery that points to the Ceph Dashboard
- set an `A` record in the DNS in MAAS to bind `ceph.maas` to `192.168.1.240`.

Now you can bring up a browser and go to `ceph.maas` to access the dash.

In your case static IPs will likely be part of what you need for you to have predictable endpoints for webapps and services and storage. Maybe MAAS when it acts as a proxy will just forward the IP.

---

If part of what you need is static IPs accessible outside the cluster in your LAN I suggest you reserve a range of IPs on your subnet that are not used by MAAS and your router. Picture included with an example that leaves 192.168.1.240-247 *unreserved* by MAAS and others.

Then Use MetalLB:

> `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/metallb/v0.8.3/manifests/metallb.yaml`

Create the following manifest for a config map that gives your load balancer a pool of IPs to use.

> `layer2.yaml`
>
> ```
>  apiVersion: v1
>  kind: ConfigMap
>  metadata:
>    namespace: metallb-system
>    name: config
>  data:
>    config: |
>      address-pools:
>      - name: my-ip-space
>        protocol: layer2
>        addresses:
>        - 192.168.1.240/29
> ```

Apply the manifest to your cluster

> `kubectl apply -f layer2.yaml`

These steps will deploy and configure a bare metal load balancer that is capable of binding to static ips that you can access outside the cluster. The above setup with its config map is set to bind to that narrow range of reserved addresses (192.168.1.240-247). If you desire a broader and/or different range this CIDR to IP range calculator helps.

https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr

After MetalLB is deployed you will need to go to the service you wish to expose internally with a static IP and change ClusterIP (or NodePort) to LoadBalancer. This will pick from the pool of IPs available to MetalLB and assign one.

Hope it goes smoothly for you. And good luck!

[image]